# AsyncTask not returning any response

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-asynctask

Hi I have trouble getting the response of my url from my host. I tried putting static variables and it worked but when I tried to use a asynctask for response it didnt work.

```
<?PHP
include_once('connection.php');

$where='';

if(isset($_GET['userLat']) && isset($_GET['userLng'])){

$where = "WHERE ((userLat >= '".addslashes($_GET['userLat'])."' AND userLat <= '".addslashes($_GET['userLat'])."' + .00901) OR (userLat <= '".addslashes($_GET['userLat'])."' AND userLat >= '".addslashes($_GET['userLat'])."' - .00901)) AND ((userLng >= '".addslashes($_GET['userLng'])."' AND userLng <= '".addslashes($_GET['userLng'])."' + .014935) OR (userLng <= '".addslashes($_GET['userLng'])."' AND userLng >= '".addslashes($_GET['userLng'])."' - .014935))";

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user ".$where." AND isOnline = 'Yes' LIMIT 1 ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$json = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $json['details'][]=$row;
}
}
mysqli_close($conn);
echo json_encode($json);
}
?>
```

AsyncTask

```
    private class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pd.setMessage("Checking nearby wingmans");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line);   //here u ll get whole response...... :-)

            }

            return buffer.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
        request = result;
        Log.d("Test", result);
    }
}
```

how i call my url

```
        btnEmergency.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = "http://10.0.2.2/wingman/emergency.php?userLat="+tvLat.getText().toString()+"ANDuserLng="+tvLng.getText().toString();
            new JsonTask().execute(url);
        }
    });
```

Thanks guys i hope i get an answer to my question. Thanks :)

Comment: is it showing any exception log?

Comment: you should really post the log , this can be a lot of reasons , Internet permission is the first thing to come to mind

Comment: @UsmanRana - no exception log either

Answer (score 0):

Very foolish of me. I jsut change the `AND` to `&` in my url
from

```
String url = "http://10.0.2.2/wingman/emergency.php?userLat="+tvLat.getText().toString()+"ANDuserLng="+tvLng.getText().toString();
```

to

```
String url = "http://10.0.2.2/wingman/emergency.php?userLat="+tvLat.getText().toString()+"&userLng="+tvLng.getText().toString();
```

And it worked. Thanks!